# SQL CASE statement specific example

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query for identifying the nodes in a tree with the parent relationship. What is wrong with this query? Even though I have inner nodes the corresponding case statement never gets executed. Always I get result as Leaf or Root nodes. Never get Inner in the output. What might I be possibly doing wrong?

> ```
> WITH CTE(N, P, [Level])
> AS
> (
>     SELECT N, P, 1 FROM
>     BST B
>     WHERE P IS NULL
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT B.N, B.P, [Level] + 1 FROM
>     BST B 
>     JOIN CTE ON B.P = CTE.N
> )
> SELECT N,
> CASE
> WHEN [Level] = 1 Then 'Root'
> WHEN [Level] < MAX([Level]) AND [Level] > 1 THEN 'Inner'
> WHEN [Level] = MAX([Level]) THEN 'Leaf'
> END
> FROM CTE
> GROUP BY N, [Level]
> ORDER BY N ASC;
> ```

Sample Input

```
N P
1 2
3 2
6 8
9 8
2 5
8 5
5 NULL
```

Sample Output

```
1 Leaf
2 Inner
3 Leaf
5 Root
6 Leaf
8 Inner
9 Leaf
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data as well so that we can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why build the hier?  Just a note, if this is a Jagged Hierarchy, the Max(Level) will not necessarily work.  For example, a leaf node is a level 3 but the max level is 6.

```
Declare @YourTable table (N int,P int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1, 2),
(3, 2),
(6, 8),
(9, 8),
(2, 5),
(8, 5),
(5, NULL)

Select A.*
      ,Lvl = case when A.P is null then 'Root' else case when B.P is null then 'Leaf' else 'Inner' end end
 From  @YourTable A
 Left Join  (Select Distinct P from @YourTable) B on A.N=B.P
```

Returns

```
N   P   Lvl
1   2   Leaf
3   2   Leaf
6   8   Leaf
9   8   Leaf
2   5   Inner
8   5   Inner
5   NULL    Root
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
WITH CTE(N, P, [Level])
AS
(
    SELECT N AS Node, N AS P, 1 as Level 
    FROM BST B
    WHERE P IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Propagate parent to all subsequent nodes
    SELECT B.N, CTE.P, Level = [Level] + 1 
    FROM BST B 
    JOIN CTE ON B.P = CTE.N
)
SELECT N, 
       CASE 
          WHEN [Level] = 1 THEN 'Root'
          WHEN [Level] > 1 AND [Level] < MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY P) THEN 'Inner'
          WHEN [Level] = MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY P) THEN 'Leaf'
       END
FROM CTE    
ORDER BY N ASC;
```

The idea is to propagate the root node down to all other nodes, so that we can apply windowed version of `MAX` with a partition by parent node clause.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ecd3/1)

Answer (score 1):

You have added `level` in `Group by` so you will not be getting the `max` level out of all the records

You can do this by using `Max Over()` window aggregate function

Here is one way

```
SELECT N,
       CASE
         WHEN [Level] = 1 THEN 'Root'
         WHEN [Level] < Max([Level]) over()
              AND [Level] > 1 THEN 'Inner'
         WHEN [Level] = Max([Level]) over() THEN 'Leaf'
       END
FROM   CTE
ORDER  BY N ASC;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the explanation.